# При использовании shift(); появляется последнее число

Tags: javascript

Простите за глупый вопрос , я просто не могу понять почему это происходит.
В перемененную  firstNum должно появится зачатие 5 потому что оно 1 в массиве , но почему то появляется 4.
Я правда искал решение , но так и не нашёл . Язык JavaScript.

```
   let num = ["1","3"];
   num.push("4"); 
   num.unshift("5");
   console.log(num);
    
   lastNum = num.pop();
   num.unshift(lastNum);
  
   firstNum= num.shift();
   num.push(firstNum);
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы удаляете первый элемент, его значение записываете в lastNum. А в следующей строке добавляете его в начало массива, вот откуда у вас 4

```
lastNum = num.pop(); // lastNum = 4
num.unshift(lastNum); // здесь массив уже будет ["4", "5", "1","3"]
```